# XSL FO running header - suppress on chapter title page

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am outputting an XML corpus to PDF using XSL-FO (via XEP processor). I am using `<fo:marker>` to putting the chapter title in a running header. It  works correctly.

However, I put a page break in so that a chapter begins on a new page with the `<chapter-title>` in big, bold font at the top of the page.

Therefore I'd like to suppress the running header for just the first page of each chapter. But I haven't been able to identify way this can be done within a attribute value or otherwise.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<fo:simple-page-master 
                master-name="page-recto"
                page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
                margin-top="3cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
                margin-left="3cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
                <fo:region-body 
                    region-name="xsl-region-body"/>
                <fo:region-before 
                    region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="12pt" padding="2cm" />
                <fo:region-after 
                    region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="12pt" padding-top="2cm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

`master-reference` with `fo:marker` for setting running header:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-recto">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block text-align="center" font-family="Times" font-size="8pt" font-style="normal" margin-bottom="1cm">           
                    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="header-chapter-title"
                         retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page"
                         retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/>
                </fo:block></fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block text-align="center" font-family="Times" font-size="8pt" font-style="normal">           
                    <fo:page-number/>
                </fo:block></fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-family="Times" font-weight="normal" font-size="10pt" space-before="10pt" space-after="10pt"
                 end-indent="120pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
 </fo:page-sequence>
```

Templates for `chapter` and `chapter-title`, with `page-break-before="always"`to trigger new page for the chapter:

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter-title">
    <fo:block text-align="left"  margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" font-family="Times" font-size="16pt" page-break-before="always">
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="header-chapter-title">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:marker>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is sample XML:

```
<corpus>
 <chapter n="1">
  <chapter-title>foo chapter title 1</chapter-title>
   <deposition>
     <deposition-title>foo title 1</deposition-title>
     <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet consectetur mi, et tincidunt lorem. In purus nunc, venenatis vitae purus eu, eleifend elementum metus.</seg>
     <seg>Integer ac varius eros. Curabitur vel venenatis odio. Vestibulum sed ultricies est, eget cursus diam.</seg>
   </deposition>
   <deposition>
     <deposition-title>foo title 2</deposition-title>
     <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet consectetur mi, et tincidunt lorem. In purus nunc, venenatis vitae purus eu, eleifend elementum metus.</seg>
     <seg>Integer ac varius eros. Curabitur vel venenatis odio. Vestibulum sed ultricies est, eget cursus diam.</seg>
   </deposition>
   <deposition>
     <deposition-title>foo title 3</deposition-title>
     <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet consectetur mi, et tincidunt lorem. In purus nunc, venenatis vitae purus eu, eleifend elementum metus.</seg>
     <seg>Integer ac varius eros. Curabitur vel venenatis odio. Vestibulum sed ultricies est, eget cursus diam.</seg>
   </deposition>
  </chapter>
<chapter n="2">
  <chapter-title>foo chapter title 2</chapter-title>
  <deposition>
     <deposition-title>foo title 1</deposition-title>
     <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet consectetur mi, et tincidunt lorem. In purus nunc, venenatis vitae purus eu, eleifend elementum metus.</seg>
     <seg>Integer ac varius eros. Curabitur vel venenatis odio. Vestibulum sed ultricies est, eget cursus diam.</seg>
  </deposition>
  <deposition>
     <deposition-title>foo title 2</deposition-title>
     <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet consectetur mi, et tincidunt lorem. In purus nunc, venenatis vitae purus eu, eleifend elementum metus.</seg>
     <seg>Integer ac varius eros. Curabitur vel venenatis odio. Vestibulum sed ultricies est, eget cursus diam.</seg>
  </deposition>
  <deposition>
     <deposition-title>foo title 3</deposition-title>
     <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet consectetur mi, et tincidunt lorem. In purus nunc, venenatis vitae purus eu, eleifend elementum metus.</seg>
     <seg>Integer ac varius eros. Curabitur vel venenatis odio. Vestibulum sed ultricies est, eget cursus diam.</seg>
  </deposition>
 </chapter>
</corpus
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also post the definition of the *page-recto* page master reference definition, along with sample XML input code. Thank you!

Comment: The post has been updated for both requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the running header from the first chapter page by:

1. Define one more `fo:simple-page-master` without `fo:region-before` for first page.
2. Define `fo:page-sequence-master/fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` that contains the reference to `fo:simple-page-master` for the first page and the rest pages.
3. Generate `fo:page-sequence` per chapter.

Here is the sample `fo:layout-master-set` code:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master 
        master-name="page-recto-first-page"
        page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
        margin-top="3cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
        margin-left="3cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
        <fo:region-body 
            region-name="xsl-region-body"  margin-bottom="12pt"/>
        <fo:region-after 
            region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="12pt"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master 
        master-name="page-recto"
        page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
        margin-top="3cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
        margin-left="3cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
        <fo:region-body 
            region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="12pt" margin-bottom="12pt"/>
        <fo:region-before 
            region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="12pt" border-bottom="1pt solid blue"/>
        <fo:region-after 
            region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="12pt"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="page-recto-psm">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-recto-first-page" page-position="first"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-recto" page-position="any"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

The sample chapter page:

[image]

The sample second page:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. Can you demonstrate some code for step #3 Generate `fo:page-sequence` per chapter? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Just figured it out, by combining with code found here: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/evenodd.html